# Text editor saving automatically unnamed buffers

Tags: linux, open-source, text-editor

Is there any free (as in beer and as in freedom) text editor that saves everything I write into it without even needing to name the file? That said, opening it again shows me the text I left.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2). Make sure the "hot_exit" option is turned on. (It is by default.)

Comment: Note that Sublime Text asks you to pay for it if you continue to use it, but there is no enforced time restriction. So in effect, you can use it forever for free if you like.

Answer (score 1):

[**CudaText**](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) is free, cross-platform, it has this feature (since last version).

If option `"ui_reopen_session": true` (default), then on closing you see dialog "Save tabs?". In dialog press "Keep session" and unnamed buffers save to session file, and auto restore later.

[image: Screenshot of 'Save tabs?' dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ is a great free editor which has this feature (and many more).
https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Did you see the `linux` tag? Not my platform.